# Irreducibility of root-height generating polynomial

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, lie-groups, polynomials, lie-algebras

The *height* $ht(\alpha)$ of a positive root $\alpha$ in a (finite, crystallographic) root system $\Phi$ is $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i$ where $\alpha = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i \alpha_i$ is its decomposition as a sum of simple roots.  I am  interested in the polynomial
$$R_{\Phi}(x):=\sum_{\alpha \in \Phi^+} x^{ht(\alpha)-1}.$$

For example (using the usual Cartan-Killing nomenclature), we have:

- $R_{A_n}(x)=n+(n-1)x+\cdots +2x^{n-2}+x^{n-1}$
- $R_{B_n}(x)=R_{A_n}(x^2)+xR_{A_{n-1}}(x^2)$
- $R_{D_n}(x)=R_{B_n}(x)-\sum_{i=n-1}^{2n-2} x^i$

**Questions:**

1. When $\Phi$ is an irreducible root system, is $R_{\Phi}(x)$ an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$?  This has been checked for the exceptional types ($G_2, F_4, E_6, E_7,$ and $E_8$) and for the infinite families listed above for $n \leq 500$.
2. If the answer to (1) is "yes", is there some uniform Lie-theoretic reason that this is true (that is, a proof not relying on the classification)?

Comment: Last I checked, it is still open to prove that $R_{A_n}$ is irreducible for all $n$, although it is known for "most" n. See "Classes of polynomials having only one non-cyclotomic irreducible factor" by Borisov, Filaseta, Lam, Trifonov.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Turning Gjergji Zaimi's comment into a community wiki answer.)

A problem equivalent to the case of $R_{A_n}$ is discussed in [Classes of polynomials having only one non-cyclotomic irreducible factor](http://doi.org/10.4064/aa-90-2-121-153), by Borisov, Filaseta, Lam, and Trifonov (*Acta Arithmetica* **90** (1999), 121–153).  They prove irreducibility in many special cases but the problem remains open (or at least, none of the papers that Google Scholar lists as citing this paper solves the problem).