# Irreducibility of a palindromic polynomial

Tags: co.combinatorics, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials

I have strong reasons to believe that the palindromic polynomial $p_n(x)$ defined by
$$p_n(x) = x^{2n}+2x^{2n-1}+3x^{2n-2}+ \cdots+ nx^{n+1}+(n+3)x^{n}+nx^{n-1}+\cdots+2x+1$$
is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. I have manually (using Mathematica) checked this for $n$ up to 100.

The Gauss Lemma does not seem to help and I have also considered the irreducibility of $p_n(x) \pmod{p}$, for some primes $p$, but these approaches provide proofs only in specific cases. How do I go about proving this in general?

Comment: I don't have any insight for your specific polynomial, but note that it looks similar to the polynomials in <https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332958/irreducibility-of-root-height-generating-polynomial> for which, according to the comment by Gjergji Zaimi, it is a well-studied and still open problem to prove irreducibility.  So there might be some technique which works for your polynomial, but you should not expect such a thing in general.

Comment: The polynomial $p_n(x)$ can also be written as
$$p_n(x) = \frac{x^{2n+2}+ 2x^{n+2} - 6x^{n+1}+2x^n+1}{(x-1)^2}.$$

Comment: for whatever it's worth, I have tested this up to $n=660,$ using Magma and the polynomial turned out to be irreducible

Comment: Also,
$$p_n(x) = \left(\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}\right)^2 + 2x^n.$$

Comment: Based on criteria (Theorem 11) in *Irreducibility Criteria for Reciprocal Polynomials and Applications* by Cafure and Cesaratto it is sufficient to show that 1) $|p_n(-1)|$ is not a perfect square (in this case simple as $|p_n(-1)| \in \{2,3\}$) and 2) $q(y)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[y]$ where $p_n(x)=x^nq(x+\frac{1}{x})$. Not sure how to prove the second part though, only I have observed that constant coefficients of $q$ are $2,3$ or $4$.