# Is the derivative of $x^n + x^{n-1} + \dots + x + 1$ irreducible?

Tags: co.combinatorics, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials

I am working on some combinatorics problems. One of my problems leads to the following question:

Is it true that the derivative of $x^n + x^{n-1} + \dots + x + 1,$ namely $nx^{n-1} + (n-1)x^{n-2} + \dots + 2x + 1$, is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$?

I believe it is true, and I have test by computers that it is true for $n \leq 100.$

Comment: Note that this polynomial is nearly the same as the Type A root poset rank generating function, which was asked about at: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332958/irreducibility-of-root-height-generating-polynomial.

Comment: Via that MO question I found http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa90/aa9023.pdf which you will be interested in

Comment: open problems are closer than one imagines...

Comment: Should this question be closed as a duplicate of the question mentioned by Sam Hopkins? I tried to vote to close as a duplicate but the system prevented me from doing so because the other question had no upvoted answer. Just now I created a community wiki answer to the other question.

Comment: I wouldn't vote as duplicate (and would vote to reopen if done) since it's not so obviously covered by the linked post (which is not easily readable without familiarity to root systems), and even if it is, the remark that this is covered by the other question makes a good answer to this one.

Comment: I asked this exact question on Math.SE four years ago https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1693589/127263

Comment: If somebody manages to write a self-contained answer it would be nice!

Comment: You may find this somewhat [related paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.00135) interesting.

Comment: I checked this with GAP for $n \leq 230$. -- No counterexample found up to that bound.

Answer (score 10):

(Turning the comments into a community wiki answer.)

This problem is discussed in [Classes of polynomials having only one non-cyclotomic irreducible factor](http://doi.org/10.4064/aa-90-2-121-153), by Borisov, Filaseta, Lam, and Trifonov (*Acta Arithmetica* **90** (1999), 121–153).  They prove irreducibility in many special cases but the problem remains open (or at least, none of the papers that Google Scholar lists as citing this paper solves the problem).