# Irreducibility of $\frac{x^{n+1}-(n+1) x+n}{(x-1)^2}$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory

The question is motivated by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3956137/fx-x20152x20143x2013-2015x2016).

Consider the polynomials
$$\dfrac{x^{n+1}-(n+1) x+n}{(x-1)^2} = \displaystyle \sum _{k=0}^n (n-k) x^k, n=1,2,3,\dots,$$

> Are they all irreducible (over $\mathbb Q$)?

I've checked small examples, such as $n=1,2,3,4,5$ and they are all irreducible. Meanwhile, I checked some larger $n$s on *Mathematica*(with the `IrreduciblePolynomialQ` function) and they are also irreducible. So I believe it's true that for any $n$, the corresponding polynomial $\displaystyle \sum _{k=0}^n (n-k) x^k$ is irreducible. **How can I prove this?**

Comment: It is not known, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/332958/30186)

Comment: Do you mean *irreducible* over $\mathbb Q$ ?

Comment: Yeah, over $\mathbb Q$

Comment: @Wojowu Oh, thanks, I see